# Typeorm migration:run can not detect created migration

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to migrate migration files created with the `migration:generate` option in Typeform.
When you run the '`migration:run`' command with the Data Source, 'Nomigrations are pending' is displayed.
I think the Data Source has set the path properly, but why is this?

data-source.ts

```html
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { User } from './entities/user.entity'

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'kochiya',
    database: 'nesttutorial',
    synchronize: true,
    entities: [User],
    migrations: [__dirname + '/src/migrations'],
});

AppDataSource.initialize();
```

[project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAW1r.png)

[folders and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78dqq.png)